# SQL Server 2008 Error - XML parsing: document parsing required too much memory

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

We've hit the wall in SQL server 2008 on the maximum number of attributes that a single XML node can have before the XML parser crashes.

The error we're receiving is:

```
Msg 6303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: Document parsing required too much memory
```

Which is a little misleading.
Out problem is happening when converting a string into an XML data type (or table column).

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, '<DataNode><Data attr1="a" attr2="b" XXXXX /></DataNode>')
```

Where *XXXXX* is actually another 8191 attributes.

In total our dataset contained 10,066 attributes to begin with.
When we reduce the number of attributes down to 8,192, it works fine. 8,193 attributes crashes however.

It doesn't seem to have anything specifically to do with the size of the data (100MB or 60KB it doesn't matter - we get the same fail/success based on attribute count)

So, is there anything that can be done with SQL server to change this limitation?

Our C# application does not have this limitation so perfectly valid XML documents in C# cannot be stored in SQL server's XML data columns.

Any help anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated. The data-structure cannot be changed at this point as it would require a re-write of the data-processing functionality of an entire application framework with hundreds of components.

PS: I have already advised the management of how ridiculous the situation is when an application stores data as attributes of a single node rather than as a tree, but this is what I have to work with :-(

**edit**: we've tried this on SQL Server 2008 32 and 64-bit versions on a server with 2GB RAM and a server with 32GB RAM - all versions and environments have the same issue.

**UPDATE:**

I've tried this in SQL server 2012, and it fails when there are 8,193 attributes AND the length of the string is also over a given size (the length of the test string is 833K), but works when the same lengths string only has 8,192 attributes.

However I have a much shorter string (193K) with 12,000 attributes and it works in SQL Server 2012, and SQL server 2008)

So, it appears to be a combination of the number of attributes when the string being cast is over a certain size.
This gets more interesting!

Thanks for the feedback so far!

**Update 2:**

After further testing with smaller strings (270K) I still hit the attribute limit at 16,384... 16,385 attributes fails!
So, it's definitely happening in increments of 8K attributes, depending on the combination of string length!!

Comment: Could you return just a varchar(max) to the C# application and let the app convert it into the proper XML format?

Comment: Unfortunately the problem isn't with the C#, we're trying to insert the XML into an XML column in SQL server and getting this error because of the number of attributes it's trying to deal with. C# does not seem to have this 8,192 attribute limitation that SQL server's XML parse has.

Comment: Ah - I misunderstood.  Sorry :(

Comment: It's entirely possible (and we're seriously considering this) that we may have to ditch the XML data-columns and convert to TEXT (blobs)... as a last resort. :-(

Comment: @doublehelix - well, the opposite question applies. Can you not convert to XML externally (e.g. in C#) and pass the XML directly to SQL for insertion?

Comment: Does your XML column have a schema defined? If yes, try it without, if no, try it with. Maybe this changes parsing.

Comment: I was trying to convert a string contained 10,100 attributes into xml data type on SQLServer2012, it works without problems

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you simply convert the attributes to elements? http://bpaste.net/show/rbPxuiDCYpUhtBaNFvBp/ Pragmatic solution.

Comment: Hey @Tomalak - when using elements there seems to be no limitation. a 2MB string with 25,000 node/elements works perfectly. (as described in the MSDN documentation, the actual limitation for an XML data-type is 2GB... it seems to be the parser that is cracking up over attributes specifically)

Comment: This isn't really an answer, neither does it solve your problem but I suggest you read this paper on how XML parsing is killing databases:http://ece.ut.ac.ir/dbrg/seminars/AdvancedDB/2007/YazdanShenas%20-%20Bandehmoghadam/Resources/MNicola_CIKM_2003_1_.pdf

Answer (score 2):

8191 attributes sounds too much. 
If looks you are trying to store actual data in the attributes - apparently SQL Server parser has a limitation here.

see article here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/05/23/605299.aspx?Redirected=true

> When a type is needed for validation, the validator loads its
>   definition from metadata and compiles it into a format suitable for
>   quick validation. In order to prevent any one type from using too much
>   memory, SQL Server caps the size of a compiled type at one megabyte.
>   SQL Server compiles all types and performs this check when the schema
>   is imported in order to avoid accepting types which exceed the limit.

I would suggest changing the way  you use XML and store you information inside element.

see 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-eleatt/index.html
and
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp

Comment: Hey @AlexTheDeveloper, thanks for the feedback. We've seen these limitations in the past and know about the depth limitations and we don't use xsd's as we have a dynamic data structure per record type. It's definitely a bad way to store data, and given the opportunity I'd love to rewrite the whole think entirely, however the schema is here to stay for now as this product is 7 years old and has billions of records over dozens of servers in client infrastructure. Looks like we're ditching the internal XML data type and moving the XML/XPath functionality to the C# layer instead... thanks again!